# React project failing to compile after changing a file name from .js to .jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've run into a bit of a snag.

I realized that a partner on my project set up a file as `.js` instead of `.jsx`. 
I switched the filetype to match the rest of the files in the project and now I'm getting hit with this error.

> index.js:1 ./src/Components/SignUp/SignUp.js Error: ENOENT: no such
>   file or directory, open '~/src/Components/SignUp/SignUp.js'

I subbed out some of the pathing for the '~'.

I've searched through my project for all instances of `SignUp` and can't find anything that would seem to lock it into looking for a .js file. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would try moving SignUp.js into a different folder entirely, and change all its `imports` appropriately, and see if that works. If it does work, THEN try moving it back and see if it still works

Comment: For the record, I prefer `.jsx` file extensions too for any file whose main exports are React components too

Comment: Alternatively, try changning the name of SignUp.js to SignUpTest.js or something and see if that compiles

Comment: Rename the file back to .js, move it to another folder, change the routes to that, then move it back, rename, then update the routes again?

Comment: If it's in `root\SignUp\SignUp.jsx` and failing to compile there, move it to `root\SignUpTest\SignUp.jsx`, fix all the imports, and try that first. I'm wondering if there's some sort of compilation cache React has and doing this will clear it from expecting the wrong file extension

Comment: Just to be clear: you want the file to be called `.jsx` right? Not `.js`? And it's `.jsx` that's failing now with the error message?

Comment: I renamed the file back to js, moved it into the testing folder and the route updated itself. I created a new jsx file in the SignUp folder, copied the code into it, changed the route, and I'm hitting that same failure to compile

Answer (score 7):

The issue resolved with the magic of turning it on and off again. Although you can add files without restarting the server, the editing of a file name (or at least file extension) requires a restart of the server.

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried yarn build too... Any solution?

Comment: Thank you, kind stranger

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and restarting the server did not fix it. The only thing that fixed it for me was deleting this folder:

`node_modules/.cache/default-development/`

Answer (score 0):

I just don't know how or why, but It worked again after to run `yarn cache clean` and restart my computer. I don't found another answer haha.

Comment: You had to restart your program or computer ?

Comment: @mishsx my computer. That was the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**yarn cache clean** does not work in my case. I deleted the file and creat it  again, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an update on this issue, please follow the solutions below; one of them should work for you.

- Restart the server.
- Remove the folders from the workspace and add them again.
- Delete the .caches/default-developmen in node_modules.
- Delete node_modules(rm -rf node_modules) and reinstall(npm install)

Hope this helps!